# Linq query with complex model mapping

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to map from my webapi to my solution some ICollection
this is a HttpClient: `var currentNotifications = await client.GetUsersAsync();`

If I have a model for example:

```
public class UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice
{
   public DeliveryType DeliveryType { get; set; }
   public NotificationGroup NotificationGroup{ get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryType
{
   public byte DeliveryTypeId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationGroup
{
   public byte NotificationGroupId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and model to map to:

```
public class NotificationListViewModel
{
  public DeliveryType DeliveryType { get; set; }
  public NotificationGroup NotificationGroup { get; set; }
}
public class DeliveryType
{
  public byte DeliveryTypeId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class NotificationGroup
{
   public int NotificationGroupId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have an **`ICollection<UserNotificationTypeDeliveryChoice> currentNotifications`** from my webapi which I need to map to

**`List<NotificationListViewModel> notificationListViewModel`**

Myexample looks like:

```
var res = currentNotifications.ToList().ForEach(x => notificationListViewModel.Add(new NotificationListViewModel()
{
    DeliveryType = new DeliveryType() {DeliveryTypeId = x.DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeId.Value, Name = x.DeliveryType.Name },
    NotificationGroup = new NotificationGroup() { NotificationGroupId = x.NotificationGroup.NotificationGroupId.Value, Name = x.NotificationGroup.Name }
}));
```

But, it reports me an error: **`CS0815 Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable`**

Ofc, if you have better solution, without ForEach I would be thankful.

Comment: did you use automapper before? i think you can't map byte directly to int

Comment: Im using automapper, but I would like rather cast byte to int

Comment: Your source samples do not contain any collection or List, where is your failing assignment ?

Comment: what if you use. BitConverter.ToInt32( x.NotificationGroup.NotificationGroupId) instead of value

Comment: Use All instead of foreach currentNotifications.ToList().Alll(...);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ForEach()` does not return anything.
You could do it with a  `Select()` call instead:

```
var result = currentNotifications.Select(x => new NotificationListViewModel
{
    DeliveryType = new DeliveryTypeViewModel
    {
        DeliveryTypeId = x.DeliveryType.DeliveryTypeId,
        Name = x.DeliveryType.Name
    },
    NotificationGroup = new NotificationGroupViewModel
    {
        NotificationGroupId = x.NotificationGroup.NotificationGroupId,
        Name = x.NotificationGroup.Name
    }
});
```

I added `ViewModel` suffix to all view model class names to make it more readable.

Comment: thanks! I started with `.Select()` but I've been lost in lambda operator and new statements heh

Answer (score 3):

The issue is here:

```
var res = currentNotifications.ToList().ForEach(...);
```

`ForEach()` returns `void` and therefore you're trying to assign `void` to `res`. That doesn't work.

First store the list, then do the `ForEach`:

```
var res = currentNotifications.ToList();

res.ForEach(...);
```

Or simply drop the `res` altogether, since you're storing the outcome in `notificationListViewModel` anyway.

```
currentNotifications.ToList().ForEach(...);
```

It depends on whether you still need `res` or not.

---

As an aside and further improvement, you're doing a LINQ `Select()` in a different way. Using the LINQ equivalent:

```
notificationListViewModel = currentNotifications.Select(x => new NotificationListViewModel() { ... });
```

Comment: I am returning res. So I really dont need res furthermore.